# Charge Distribution on a Strip

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, charge, microwaves

let's consider a microstrip line connected to a voltage source V0 (applied between the strip and GND plane). According to foundation for microwave engineering (collin) book, the surface charge density on the strip is the following one:

[image]

[image]

I am looking for a **physical explanation** of this behaviour.

Precisely, let's consider the instant in which the microstrip line is connected to the voltage generator. Step by step:

1) The voltage source provides many positive charges at its positive terminal and many negative charges at its negative terminal. Let's focus on the first one, which is directly connected to the strip.

2) Charges provided by the voltage source will try to distance themselves due to Coulomb repulsion and will go predominantly at the edges of the strip (this may explain the reason by which the surface density is infinite at the edges of the graph).

3) The voltage source will provide other charges which I think will go at the center of the strip. How will the charge distribution be influenced by this factor?

4) Where will the following charges locate?

Comment: What do you mean by "voltage source"? Is it an AC source or a DC source? If it's an AC source, then the skin effect probably explains it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect

Comment: I have understood now that it is a DC source. It is a static analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The electrons repel each other so they want to be the further away the possible. So naturally they accumulate at the edge of the strip. Many popular EM textbooks deal with the similar problem of finding the distribution of charge across an isolated thin rod by using the (numerical) Method of Moments.

Comment: But if almost all electrons accumulate at the edge of the strip, then the next electrons will go at the centre (I think) because now there is higher repulsion at the edge, so I do not have a clear idea of what happens

Comment: During the whole process, the electrons repel eachother. The charge in the centre eill continue to build up there, but the electron density at the edges will rise even further, and at all tines it will be greater than the one in the centre of the strip